# Hide cancel button between the 20th and the 3rd of the month (Woocommerce Subscriptions)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm working on Woocommerce Subscriptions.

The code below hides the 'cancel' and 'reactivate' buttons, except for a specific product (ID:1812).

I would like to go deeper and **hide the 'cancel' and 'reactivate' button between the 20th and the 3rd of the month**.

Could you help me to achieve that?

```js
/**
 * Remove the "Change Payment Method" button from the My Subscriptions table.
 *
 * This isn't actually necessary because @see eg_subscription_payment_method_cannot_be_changed()
 * will prevent the button being displayed, however, it is included here as an example of how to
 * remove just the button but allow the change payment method process.
 */
function eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button( $actions, $subscription ) {
   $is_my_product = false;
   if ( sizeof( $subscription_items = $subscription->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
     foreach ( $subscription_items as $item_id => $item ) {
         $product = $item->get_product();
         if ( $product->get_id() == 1812 ) {
            $is_my_product = true;
            break;
         }
     }
   }
   if ( $is_my_product ) return $actions;

    foreach ( $actions as $action_key => $action ) {
        switch ( $action_key ) {
            case 'change_payment_method':   // Hide "Change Payment Method" button?
//          case 'change_address':      // Hide "Change Address" button?
//          case 'switch':          // Hide "Switch Subscription" button?
//          case 'resubscribe':     // Hide "Resubscribe" button from an expired or cancelled subscription?
//          case 'pay':         // Hide "Pay" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold" as they require payment?
            case 'reactivate':      // Hide "Reactive" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold"?
            case 'cancel':          // Hide "Cancel" button on subscriptions that are "active" or "on-hold"?
                unset( $actions[ $action_key ] );
                break;
            default: 
                error_log( '-- $action = ' . print_r( $action, true ) );
                break;
        }
    }

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button', 100, 2 );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if today's date is after the 19th of current month or before the 4th of the month like this.

Get today's date:

```
date( 'j' )
```

Check if inside $n->$m range:

```
date( 'j' ) > $n-1 && date( 'j' ) < $m+1
```

Finally:

```
function eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button( $actions, $subscription ) {
   $is_my_product = false;
   if ( sizeof( $subscription_items = $subscription->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
     foreach ( $subscription_items as $item_id => $item ) {
         $product = $item->get_product();
         if ( $product->get_id() == 1812 ) {
            $is_my_product = true;
            break;
         }
     }
   }
   if ( $is_my_product ) return $actions;

   if ( date( 'j' ) > 3 && date( 'j' ) < 20 ) return $actions;

    foreach ( $actions as $action_key => $action ) {
        switch ( $action_key ) {
            case 'change_payment_method':   // Hide "Change Payment Method" button?
//          case 'change_address':      // Hide "Change Address" button?
//          case 'switch':          // Hide "Switch Subscription" button?
//          case 'resubscribe':     // Hide "Resubscribe" button from an expired or cancelled subscription?
//          case 'pay':         // Hide "Pay" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold" as they require payment?
            case 'reactivate':      // Hide "Reactive" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold"?
            case 'cancel':          // Hide "Cancel" button on subscriptions that are "active" or "on-hold"?
                unset( $actions[ $action_key ] );
                break;
            default: 
                error_log( '-- $action = ' . print_r( $action, true ) );
                break;
        }
    }

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but it doesn't work :( I tried it and found two issues : 

1/ The cancel button reappears again for all the products (not only on the product "1812").

2/ I tried to modify the "20" by "14" to check if the cancel button would disappear, but it's still here.

Comment: Hey @AlexisPereira thanks for your feedback! My date check is after your product ID check, so issue 1/ should not happen. Up until that line code is the exact same as yours, so I'm surprised. Was your code working for disabling on product 1812?

Comment: In regard to issue 2/ that's weird, I'll check this out on my test environment

Comment: I confirm, issue 2/ is not happening on my test website, cancel button is correctly removed if I enter e.g. "> 3 && < 15". So there's something else in your install